# Can't connect to the database with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having issues when I try to connect to mongodb with mongoose. I created an admin/admin user, but when I try to change it, it doesn't work.
I'm using mongoose 5.0.6 and mongo 4.0.5

This is my mongo user :

```
> db.getUsers()
[
    {
        "_id" : "mydb.admin",
        "user" : "admin",
        "db" : "mydb",
        "roles" : [
            {
                "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
                "db" : "admin"
            }
        ],
        "mechanisms" : [
            "SCRAM-SHA-1",
            "SCRAM-SHA-256"
        ]
    }]
```

And this is how I connect to mongoose :

```
  let options = {    
    user: 'admin',
    pass: "admin",
    useNewUrlParser: true,

  }
  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbConfig.host}:${dbConfig.port}/${dbConfig.dbConfig.database}`, options);
```

This works.

Now when I try to change the password :

```
 db.updateUser("admin", { pwd: "admin2" })
```

I got the following error :

```
MongoError: Authentication failed.
```

So I tried to log in directly with mongo command (note the authentication database):

```
mongo --username admin --password --authenticationDatabase mydb --host XXX --port 27017
```

I can authenticate properly, but not with mongoose. So I try to add the *authSource* parameter

```
  let options = {    
    user: 'admin',
    pass: "admin2",
    useNewUrlParser: true,

  }
  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${dbConfig.dbConfig.host}:${dbConfig.dbConfig.port}/${dbConfig.dbConfig.database}?authSource=${dbConfig.dbConfig.database}`, options);
```

I have an authentication error. This is my connection code :

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.on('connected', () => {
    server.listen(
      port,
      function() {
        console.log(`Listen on port ${port}`);
        console.log(`Environnement is ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`);
        console.log(`database connected ${dbConfig.dbConfig.host} ${dbConfig.dbConfig.database}`)
      });
  }
);
```

There is also a wierd behaviour according to the following scenarios : (after changing the password)

- Wrong credentials (admin/admin) + no authSource => throw an Error event (authentication failed)
- Wrong credentials (admin/admin) + authSource => throw an Error event (authentication failed)
- Correct credentials + authSource => goes to 'connected event' but display a Authentication failed error
- Correct credentials + no authSource => same as above

So whenever I change the credentials it throw an Error, but I am able to authenticate to the database with mongoshell.

Finally, if I change back the credentials to "admin/admin" it works perfectly.

TLDR :

- Try to change my mongo's user password to admin2
- Works with mongoshell but not with the app
- Looks like it only works with admin as password and no authSource